# Infinite loop in own sorting function in python

Tags: python, loops

I am very new to python, and as excersize I want to write sorting function just with my little knowledge of python. But my code ends in infinite loop, but I cant figure out why. Can anybody help?

here is my code

```
#create list
sezn = []
while True:
    try :
        a = int(input("Number: "))
        sezn.append(a)
    except :
        break
#print min, max and mean
print (sezn)
print("minimum: ", min(sezn))
print ("maximum: ", max(sezn))
fin = 0
for i in sezn:
    fin += i
mean = fin/len(sezn)
print ("mean: ", mean)
#sorting function    
sort = []
sez = []
index = 0
length = len(sezn)
print (length)
while index < length:
    for i in sezn:
        if i == min(sezn):
            sort.append(i)
        else:
            sez.append(i)
    index += 1
    sezn = sez
print(sort)
```

Comment: you are basically doing `for i in a: a.append(i)`, so it cannot end.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to set `sez` to an empty list during the while loop:

```
while index < length:
    sez = [] # <-- need to add this line, and you can also get rid of this from before the while loop
    for i in sezn:
        if i == min(sezn):
            sort.append(i)
        else:
            sez.append(i)
    index += 1
    sezn = sez
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop is infinite cause you dont get out of it.

if you just want the to get out of the loop. Then:

```
sezn = []
while True:
    try :
        a = int(input("Number: "))
        sezn.append(a)
        break
    except :
    break
```

Comment: I think he means the sort part.  To get out of the input loop he just enters non integer

Comment: No. Its a a while loop that is set to True, so it will go on even if he enters an integer. Try to run the code.

Comment: He has to e.g. set  while len(sezn) != 1: if he wants to stop the loop upon entering one integer.